# Postgres Concate: Date + Timestamp + Integer of 7

Tags: postgresql

How can I combine these two columns and add integer of 7 to it? In postgres.

Both columns are in the table a_event.
start_time is a timestamp without time zone data type.
start_date is a date data type.

so far I have:

```
SELECT start_time || start_date AS start_date_time
FROM a_event;
```

This works but it shows:
    2015-03-06 21:17:162015-02-06

How can I get it to simply show: 
2015-03-06 13:17:16 with an added 7 days so: 2015-03-13 in the desired result.

Comment: What data type is `start_time` and `start_date` and why don't you store that in a single `timestamp` column?

Comment: Please can you [edit] the question to give us a complete example with input as well as output. Maybe add it on a http://sqlfiddle.com as well. It's hard to tell why you get the output you do without knowing anything about the input.

Comment: `start_time + interval '7' day` or simply `start_time + 7`

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator concatenates two strings, so the 'start_time' and 'start_date' columns are converted to `text` and then concatenated to give the result you see.

You want to add 7 days to the starting date. That is simply:

```
SELECT start_date + 7 AS start_date_time
FROM a_event;
```

On a `date` data type the `+` operator adds a number of days.

If you want to keep the starting time information, the solution is slightly more complex:

```
SELECT start_time + interval '7 days' AS start_date_time
FROM a_event;
```

The `timestamp` data type records microseconds since 01-01-1970, so you have to explicitly indicate that you want to add an interval of 7 days (and not 7 microseconds).